# MATLAB: Read HTML-Codes (within XML)

Tags: html, xml, matlab, unicode, polish

I'm trying to read the following XML-file of a Polish treebank using MATLAB: http://zil.ipipan.waw.pl/Sk%C5%82adnica?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=Sk%C5%82adnica-frazowa-0.5-TigerXML.xml.gz

Polish letters seem to be encoded as HTML-codes: http://webdesign.about.com/od/localization/l/blhtmlcodes-pl.htm

For instance, `&#322;` stands for 'ł'. If I open the treebank using 'UTF-8', I get words like `k&#322;ania&#322;`, which should actually be displayed as 'kłaniał'

Now, I see 2 options to read the treebank correctly:

1. Directly read the XML-file such that HTML-codes are transformed into the corresponding characters.
2. First save the words in non-decoded format (e.g. as `k&#322;ania&#322;`) and then transform the characters afterwards.

Is it possible to do one of the 2 options (or both) in MATLAB?

Comment: Did you try [xmlread](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xmlread.html)? For me it automatically unescapes those characters.

Comment: You can download the treebank I'm trying to analyze here: http://zil.ipipan.waw.pl/Sk%C5%82adnica?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=Sk%C5%82adnica-frazowa-0.5-TigerXML.xml.gz


I did try 'xmlread'. Sadly, the xml-file is too huge to be opened with that function, so I'm using 'fopen' instead.

Answer (score 0):

A non-MATLAB solution is to preprocess the file through some external utility. For instance, with Ruby installed, one could use the `HTMLentities` gem to unescape all the special characters.

```
sudo gem install htmlentities
```

Let `file.xml` be the filename which should consist of ascii-only chars. The Ruby code to convert the file could be like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'htmlentities'
xml = File.open("file.xml").read
converted_xml = HTMLEntities.new.decode xml
IO.write "decoded_file.xml", xml
```

(To run the file, don't forget to `chmod +x` it to make it executable).
Or more compactly, as a one-liner

```
 ruby -e "require 'htmlentities';IO.write(\"decoded_file.xml\",HTMLEntities.new.decode(File.open(\"file.xml\").read))"
```

You could then postprocess the xml however you wish.